# How can I provision device farm not in "us-west-2" region by using device farm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-device-farm

I want to provision device farm on AWS by using Terraform. But from the [doc of Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/devicefarm_project.html), the aws_devicefarm_project feature is only supported on the "us-west-2" region. So please anyone know how should I do this if my service is not on the "us-west-2" region?

Comment: AWS Device Farm at present is only available in us-west-2 region, so this isn't a limitation on the Terraform side. You need to wait until AWS makes the farm available in your intended region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Device Farm is only available in `us-west-2`.

Source: [AWS Regional Table.](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/)

Comment: Thank you! I have thought it's some issue about terraform. It turns out it's because AWS.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Device Farm API calls and console are accessible globally.
Not sure about the Terraform note and implementation but you should be able to use Device Farm from all regions.
The resources in AWS Device Farm will get created in us-west-2 region irrespective of the region from where they were called but the calls can be made from any region.

Hope that helps.